# Implementing two arraylists in another class

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm going totally nuts on my `BankLogic` now. Three classes, `Customer`, `SavingsAccount` and `BankLogic` where I want to create customers and savings accounts. 
I have two methods that works fine, `addCustomer()` (where I add customers to arraylist `Customer`) and `addSavingsAccount()` (where I add savings accounts to customers with certain `pNr`). My problem is that I don't know how to print stuff out from two arraylists that somehow have to be linked together. How do I do that?

This method is Ok if I only have `info = customer.toString()`. How do I get the right `accountId` to the `pNr`? I know I can't fetch it from `SavingsAccount`, it will generate a new number. But how do I do?

BankLogic class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankLogic
{
private double amount;
private double balance;
private ArrayList<Customer> customerlist;
private ArrayList<SavingsAccount> accounts;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

public BankLogic()
{
    customerlist = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    accounts = new ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();
}
public String infoBank()
{
    String customers = customerlist.toString();
    return customers.substring(1, customers.length() - 1);
}
public boolean addCustomer(String name, long pNr)
{
boolean add = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < customerlist.size(); i++)
    {
        if (customerlist.get(i).getPCode() == pNr)
        {
            add = false;
        }
    }

    if(add)
    {
        customerlist.add(new Customer(name, pNr));
        add = true;
    }

    return add;

}
public String infoCustomer(long pNr){

    String info = "";
    for (Customer customer : customerlist)
    {
        if (customer.getPCode() == pNr)
        {
                info = customer.toString() + "\tKontonr: " + findAccount(pNr); 
        }
     } 
    return info;
}
public String findAccount(long pNr){

    for(SavingsAccount account : accounts)
    {
      if (account.getPCode() == pNr)
       {
         return "account found";
       }
    }
 return "Nothing found";
}
public boolean changeCustomerName(String name, long pNr){

boolean result = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < customerlist.size(); i++)
    {
        if (customerlist.get(i).getPCode() == pNr)
        {
            Customer customer = customerlist.get(i);
            customer.setName(name);
            customerlist.set(i, customer);
            result = true;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
public String removeCustomer(long pNr){

    for (int i = 0; i < customerlist.size(); i++)
    {
        Customer customer = customerlist.get(i);
        if (customer.getPCode() == pNr)
        {
            customer = customerlist.remove(i);
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
    return "Removeinfo: ";

}
public int addSavingsAccount(long pNr){
    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < customerlist.size(); i++)
    {
        accounts.add(new SavingsAccount());
    }
    return SavingsAccount.getAccountId();
    */


    int add = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < customerlist.size(); i++)
    {
        if (customerlist.get(i).getPCode() == pNr)
        {
            accounts.add(new SavingsAccount());
        }
        else
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return add;

}
public String infoAccount(long pNr, int accountId)
{
    String info = "";
    for(Customer customer : customerlist)
    {
        if(pNr == customer.getPCode())
        {
            for(SavingsAccount account : accounts)
            {
                if(accountId == account.getAccountId())
                {
                    info = "Personnummer: " + pNr + "\nKontonummer: " + accountId
                    + "\nSaldo: " + amount + "\nRänta: " + SavingsAccount.RATE;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return info; 
}
public boolean deposit(long pNr, int accountId, double amount)
{   
    for(Customer customer : customerlist)
    {
        for (SavingsAccount account : accounts)
            {
                if(accountId == account.getAccountId() && pNr == customer.getPCode())
                {
                     balance += amount;
                     return true;
                }
            }
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean withdraw(long pNr, int accountId, double amount){

    for(Customer customer : customerlist)
    {
        if(pNr == customer.getPCode())
        {
            for(SavingsAccount account : accounts)
            {
                if(accountId == account.getAccountId())
                {
                    balance -= amount;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


//stänger ett konto och returnerar saldo och ränta
public String closeAccount(long pNr, int accountId){

            if(customerlist.size() > accountId)
            {
                balance = SavingsAccount.getBalance();
                customerlist.remove(accountId);
            }

            return  "Saldo: " + balance + "\nRänta: " + SavingsAccount.getIntRate();
}
```

}

SavingsAccount class

```
public class SavingsAccount
{
private static double balance;
private static String accounttype = "Sparkonto";
private static int accountId = 1001;
public static final double RATE = 2.0;
private long pNr;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar kundens personnummer
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: long returnerar personnummer
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public long getPCode(){
   return pNr;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar saldo
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: double returnerar saldo
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar kontotyp
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: String returnerar kontotyp
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static String getAccountType(){
    return accounttype;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar kontonummer
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: int returnerar kontonummer
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static int getAccountId(){
    return accountId++;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar ränta
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: double returnerar räntesatsen
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static double getIntRate(){
    return RATE;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: beräknar ränta per år
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: double returnerar saldot inkl. årsräntan i kronor
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static double calculateIntRate(){
    return balance += (balance * RATE) / 100;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: utför transaktioner; insättning / uttag, och lämnar 
// meddelande om kontot understiger 0
// (Här fick jag hjälp från en föreläsning från Chalmers.
// http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2009/course/TDA143/Lectures/F5.pdf)
// Inparametrar: double amount
// Returvärde: double returnerar nytt saldo om det finns täckning på konto
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public double transaction(double amount){

    if(amount < 0 && balance + amount < 0)
        return -0;
    else
        return balance += amount;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: variablerna blir utskrivbara
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: String returnerar kontonummer, kontotyp, saldo och ränta
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public String toString(){
    String infoAccount = "Kontonr: " + accountId + "\nKontotyp: " + accounttype +
    "\nSaldo: " + balance + "\tRäntesats: " + RATE;
    return infoAccount;
}
}
```

Customer class:

```
public class Customer
{
private String name;
private long pNr;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: konstruktor
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public Customer(String cName, long pCode)
{
    name = cName;
    pNr = pCode;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar kundens namn
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: String returnerar namn
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public String getName(){
    return name;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar kundens personnummer
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: long returnerar personnummer
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public long getPCode(){
    return pNr;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: ändrar en kunds namn
// Inparametrar: String newName - nytt namn genereras
// Returvärde: String returnerar kundens nya namn
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void setName(String newName){
    name = newName;
}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: skriver ut all info om kunden
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: String returnerar personnummer och namn
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public String toString(){
    return "\nPersonnummer: " + pNr + "\tNamn: " + name; 
}
}
```

Comment: HAve you got two listst One Holding Customer and One holding accounts ?

Comment: Is this question about data structure? Post you Customer and SavingsAccount classes.

Comment: @KennethClark Yes
private ArrayList<Customer> customerlist;
private ArrayList<SavingsAccount> accounts;
public BankLogic()
 {
  customerlist = new ArrayList<Customer>();
  accounts = new ArrayList<SavingsAccount>();
 }

Comment: rather add the accounts list on the customer , the account must be linked to the customer parent class by the customer ID / primary key. That way customers have a list of accounts for each customer and the for each account on customer to get the desired results.

Comment: @AndreasM. Updated my code with the classes.

Comment: @KennethClark. I guess that's the easiest way to do it? I put an arraylist SavingsAccount to Customer and delete it from the BankLogic class?

Comment: Exactly , the idea is ownership .. you want customers to have accounts or accounts to have customers. Its really up to the business use case. I see you also need a primary key on the account (unless you are useing a document database like mongo). I would sugest then adding a method find saving account to get the account you are looking for. My other sugestion would be to create an account interface and saving account implement that interface. Use the interface as the type you are storing in the accounts list. that way you can expand to have credit accounts and current accounts.

Comment: @Kenneth Clark. I will try this out. Though I'm new to java I probably come back with a new question. Hold your thumbs for not. ;-)

Comment: Is it possible to make a BankLogic object of the two arraylists?

Comment: It is indeed, you just need a link between the client and the account, so if you add a unique id like account id on account then add that as a memeber veriable on client , then you can get teh account associated to the client , or you can go the other way around. Account has a member variable customer id which then lets you know which customer belongs to that client. (This is a very slow way of looking for accounts to customers). The best aproach will be to add an account to the client object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SavingsAccount class needs an accountId as an instance variable that gets assigned by the constructor.  Change your current static accountId to something like nextAccountId.  You probably don't want balance to be static either since each account needs its own value.

```
    public class SavingsAccount()
    {
      private static int nextAccountId = 1001;
      private int accountId;
      private double balance = 0.0;

      private int getNextAccountId()
      {
          return nextAccountId++;
      }

      public SavingsAccount()
      {
        accountId = getNextAccountId();
      }

      public int getAccountId()
      {
          return accountId();
      }

      public double getBalance()
      {
          return balance;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I had some pretty weird things goingon when I had a constructor in SavingsAccount. But I guess it's better to put the arraylist SavingsAccounts to Customer and delete it from BankLogic?

Comment: I can't really answer this question because I don't know what BankLogic is doing.

I think you really need to spend some time understanding what the keyword _static_ does.  When you declare a class variable as static, it means that there is only one value for the whole class. Non-static variable values are unique per instance.

If you are going to turn this programming exercise into a useful example, you are going to need to have instances of SavingsAccount with different IDs and balances. That means you are going to need a constructor and the Id and balance variables should not be _static_.

Comment: YES of course! Now I understood that. If you drop an account you want the other accounts to be the same, not changed! :-)

Comment: But when I changed I got this "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getAccountId() from the type SavingsAccount" in my addsavingsAccount above. :-(

Comment: If you remove the static keyword from a member of a class, you need to make sure that the getters and setters also do not have the static keyword.  If the member is not static, you must access it via an instance like account.getBalance(), or account.getAccountId().  Notice that in my example, the getAccountId() and getBalance() methods are not declared as static.Suppose you kept a count of instances like `static int count=0;`.  The accessor would be `public static int getCount()` and you would call it as `SavingsAccount.getCount()`.

Comment: It would be nice if you accepted my answer as the one that solves your problem.  Gotta start earning reputation points somehow :).

Answer (score 0):

SavingsAccount

```
public class SavingsAccount
{
  private static double balance;
  private static String accounttype = "Sparkonto";
  private static int accountId = 1001;
  public static final double RATE = 2.0;
  private long pNr;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar kundens personnummer
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: long returnerar personnummer
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public long getPCode(){
   return pNr;
}



//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar saldo
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: double returnerar saldo
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar kontotyp
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: String returnerar kontotyp
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static String getAccountType(){
    return accounttype;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar kontonummer
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: int returnerar kontonummer
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static int getAccountId(){
    return accountId++;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: hämtar ränta
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: double returnerar räntesatsen
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static double getIntRate(){
    return RATE;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: beräknar ränta per år
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: double returnerar saldot inkl. årsräntan i kronor
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public static double calculateIntRate(){
    return balance += (balance * RATE) / 100;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: utför transaktioner; insättning / uttag, och lämnar 
// meddelande om kontot understiger 0
// (Här fick jag hjälp från en föreläsning från Chalmers.
// http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2009/course/TDA143/Lectures/F5.pdf)
// Inparametrar: double amount
// Returvärde: double returnerar nytt saldo om det finns täckning på konto
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public double transaction(double amount){

    if(amount < 0 && balance + amount < 0)
        return -0;
    else
        return balance += amount;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// Beskrivning: variablerna blir utskrivbara
// Inparametrar: 
// Returvärde: String returnerar kontonummer, kontotyp, saldo och ränta
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
public String toString(){
    String infoAccount = "Kontonr: " + accountId + "\nKontotyp: " + accounttype +
    "\nSaldo: " + balance + "\tRäntesats: " + RATE;
    return infoAccount;
}
}
```

loop through the results

```
public String infoCustomer(long pNr){

    String info = "";
    for (Customer customer : customerlist)
    {
        if (customer.getPCode() == pNr)
        {
                info = customer.toString() + "\tKontonr: " + findAccount(pNr); 
        }
     } 
    return info;
}

public String findAccount(long pNr){

    for(SavingsAccount account in accounts)
    {
      if (account.getPCode() == pNr)
       {
         return "account found";
       }
    }
 return "Nothing found";
}
```

Comment: I see this should be the right way to do it, but the result is unfortunately "Nothing found"

Comment: I have updated my addSavingsAccount. Could it be something wrong there? It works fine when I'm testing it, but maybe it should be modified?

Comment: your pNr are probably 0. Did you update this in the database and when you create the savingaccount you set the pr number to the customer pr number?

Comment: I don't work with a database. But where do I set the pr number to the customer pr number?

Comment: Well you have a list of Customers , when you create the SavingsAccount i.e new SavingsAccount() call setPrNo(customer.getPrNo()); that way you have a link from the customer to the Account.

Comment: Problem is I don't have any setPNr. You shouldn't be able to manipulate the pNr. :-(